# UITableView custom begin and end updates animation

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView`, I want to customize animation duration of begin and end update.

If it is 0.2 then I want to make it as 0.5.

```
[tbl beginUpdates];
[tbl reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
[tbl endUpdates];
```

Above lines animation duration needs to be very slow for me.